# Linking to new dynamic route won't change getInitialProps data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I can't understand when to use `componentDidMount` and `getInitialProps`. I've actually tried researching them a lot but I can't quite work out in my instance when to use which one.

Here is the premise. I have a page /content/[uniqueid].js
I need to use that ID to query a DB and collect information.
I can currently do all of that but if I am on /content/23 and I click a link to go to /content/24 it doesn't refresh and query the DB so I am stuck with the current data until I hard refresh or navigate away.

My code looks like this (At the moment)

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
      const props = await axios
       .post('/api/details', { uid: query.uniqueid})
       .then((res) => {
         if (res.data.response.boolean) {
           return {
             contentId: query.uniqueid,
             details: res.data.payload[0],
           }
         }
       })
       .catch((e) => {
         //Not Found
       })
     return props
   }

   render() {
       return (
            //Output data
       )
   }
```

So firstly, is it even possible to get `query` in componentDidMount?
Does `componentDidMount` run every time while `getInitialProps` only run on an initial render?
Do I need to use `componentDidUpdate` to check whether it changed?

Some explanation on what I am doing wrong would be great.

From reading I'm convinced I should use `getInitialProps` but I can't get it to work properly.

How would you do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you have in `render`? Also, not related to the issue but Next.js now recommends using [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) rather than `getInitialProps`.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a super weird issue. Installing [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pwa/) plugin in an unrelated wordpress site actually cached the PWA settings on any localhost:3000 website.
I changed my config to build on 3002 and it works fine. Super annoying but my getInitialProps and content is now working as expected.